# Get the sum of time given in TCL

Tags: tcl

I want to add all time given with the format:

> 000:00:00
>   00 00:00:00

```
set t1 [clock scan "009:05:07"]
set t2 [clock scan "023:05:55"]
set sum [expr {$y1 + $y2}]
set total [clock format $sum -format {%H:%M:%S}]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question? I'll take a guess, but it's probably going to be completely off…

Answer (score 1):

The `clock` command deals in times, not time intervals. This means that when you parse an interval with `clock scan`, you have your current timezone added into the mix as well, and when you convert back with `clock format`, you take each value modulo the number of elapsed days. Plus whatever is going on with the timezone. It won't work right.

What I think you want is best done with basic `scan` and `format` and some simple arithmetic.

```
set t1 "009:05:07"
set t2 "023:05:55"

# Parse the intervals
scan $t1 "%d:%d:%d" h1 m1 s1
scan $t2 "%d:%d:%d" h2 m2 s2

# Perform the arithmetic; remember that / is an integer operator here and % is the remainder
set s3 [expr {$s1 + $s2}]
set m3 [expr {$m1 + $m2 + $s3/60}]
set s3 [expr {$s3 % 60}]
set h3 [expr {$h1 + $h2 + $m3/60}]
set m3 [expr {$m3 % 60}]

# Reassemble into the output format
set total [format "%03d:%02d:%02d" $h3 $m3 $s3]
```

Comment: If you're dealing with more complex formats, you check the result of `scan` (which is the number of `%`-fields handled) and fix up the variables afterwards. The code to do this is longer than I want to write, but fundamentally fairly simple. Write a helper procedure if you're doing this.

Comment: But what if I have a list of time like {009:05:07 023:05:55 015:01:04} and I will get there sum?

Comment: @aresjay You can create a `proc` then loop through the items in your list.